# 404 not found vercel deploying nextjs?

Tags: next.js, vercel

[image: https://gyazo.com/62d0e76a8194422f448361314345829a]

This is for my portfolio website. It was working before. I changed like one line that shouldn't effect anything to update my profile then redeployed it, and it just shows this. I tried every solution I could find over the internet with this error but nothing is fixing it?? It works locally.

These are the build logs??

```
Cloning github.com/xxxxx/portfolio (Branch: main, Commit: d4beb3c)
Cloning completed: 1.157s
Installing build runtime...
Build runtime installed: 1.977s
No Build Cache available
Installing dependencies...
yarn install v1.22.17
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "@emotion/react > @emotion/babel-plugin@11.9.2" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0".
warning "@emotion/react > @emotion/babel-plugin > @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx@7.17.12" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 38.08s.
Running "yarn run build"
yarn run v1.22.17
$ next build
Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
https://nextjs.org/telemetry
info  - Checking validity of types...
info  - Creating an optimized production build...
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Collecting page data...
info  - Generating static pages (0/3)
info  - Generating static pages (3/3)
info  - Finalizing page optimization...
Page                                       Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ / (734 ms)                             58.2 kB         134 kB
├   /_app                                  0 B            75.4 kB
├ ○ /404                                   193 B          75.6 kB
└ λ /api/hello                             0 B            75.4 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all              75.4 kB
  ├ chunks/framework-a87821de553db91d.js   45 kB
  ├ chunks/main-04ef9a4c5c83921e.js        28.9 kB
  ├ chunks/pages/_app-43ac001d99fedbd3.js  493 B
  ├ chunks/webpack-fd1bc4a65a80e5c8.js     968 B
  └ css/26d0985ae8dac800.css               168 B
λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
Next.js Analytics is enabled for this production build. You'll receive a Real Experience Score computed by all of your visitors.
Done in 24.82s.
Generated build outputs:
 - Static files: 12
 - Serverless Functions: 0
 - Edge Functions: 0
Deployed outputs in 1s
Build completed. Populating build cache...
Uploading build cache [45.15 MB]...
Build cache uploaded: 2.332s
Done with "package.json"
```

Again, I didn't make a significant change at all. It was working before.

Comment: Your build logs show success. There is nothing we can tell from them. We'd need debugging details (some code and/or your deployed URL). Also, are you sure you are opening correct URL? Vercel shows them at top (in deployment/domains). If everything is correct, there might be some cache issue (although its less likely to give 404). You can also try redeploying.

Comment: Found the issue after looking through the settings. Apparently they defaulted my framework preset to 'none' without me doing anything. Fixed it by setting it back to next

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vercel defaulted my app's framework preset to none without me doing anything which caused this error. Leaving this here in case others faced a similar issue with their app.

To fix this just go to your app > settings > change framework preset to next or CRA whichever you used.